# Computing the kernel of a $k$-algebra homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, proof-explanation

I am trying to understand the proof of the following result on the the kernels of $k$-algebra homomorphisms (in particular this is part of Dummit & Foote proposition 8 of section 15.1)

Let $k$ be a field, $J$ be an ideal of $k[y_1,...,y_m]$ and $I$ be an ideal of $k[x_1,...,x_n]$ and let $\Phi$ be a $k$-algebra homomorphism
$$
\Phi:k[y_1,...,y_m]/J \to k[x_1,...,x_n]/I
$$
For $1\leq i \leq m$, let $\varphi_i \in k[x_1,...,x_n]$ represent the coset of $\Phi(y_i)$, i.e. $\Phi(y_i) = \varphi_i + I \in k[x_1,...,x_n]/I$. Let $R = k[y_1,...,y_m,x_1,...,x_n]$ and $\mathcal{A}$ be the ideal in $R$ generated by all of the generators of $I$ along with $y_1-\varphi_1,y_2-\varphi_2,...,y_m-\varphi_m$. Then the $\ker \Phi$ is $\mathcal{A} \cap k[y_1,...,y_m]$ taken modulo $J$.

First we are trying to show $\mathcal{A} \cap k[y_1,...,y_m]$ is contained in the kernel. Let $f_1,...,f_s$ denote the generators for $I$ in $k[x_1,...,x_n]$. The book begins this proof by taking an arbitrary $f \in \mathcal{A} \cap k[y_1,...,y_m]$ and writing
$$
f = \sum_{i=1}^na_i(y_i-\varphi_i) + \sum_{j=1}^sb_jf_j
$$
where $a_1,...,a_n,b_1,...,b_s \in R = k[y_1,...,y_m,x_1,...,x_n]$. I have two main questions about this expression:

1.) Both the $\varphi_i$'s and the $f_j$ are polynomials in $k[x_1,...,x_n]$, but $f$ is a polynomial only in $\mathcal{A} \cap k[y_1,...,y_m]\subseteq k[y_1,...,y_m]$ i.e. it is a polynomial only in $y_i$'s, so how do we know that all the $x$'s have to cancel each other out in the end.

2.) The first sum in the expression is a sum of $n$ terms, but the $y_i$'s and $\varphi_i$'s are indexed $1$ through $m$, so why does this make sense? (It's possible for example, that $m<n$ in which case I don't see how this is a meaningful expression)

Am I missing something obvious? Is there a typo in the indices? Some help in parsing the expression would be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The polynomials $\varphi_i$ and $f_j$ are considered as living inside $k[x_1,...,x_n,y_1,...,y_m]$, via the inclusion of $k[x_1,...,x_n]$. Since $f$ lies in $\mathcal{A}$, it is of the form $\sum_{i=1}^ma_i(y_i-\varphi_i)+\sum_{j=1}^sb_jf_j$, so there is a typo in the book. As you point out, if $n>m$ then $y_n$ is not defined. Also, the $x_i$'s cancel out because you impose that $f$ lies in $\mathcal{A}\cap k[y_1,...,y_m]$ (and not the other way around).

Comment: Of course, this makes a lot of sense, I think I was just confused by the switched indices and thought I understood less than I did